# Custom Taxonomy dont save in a frontend form for post a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, terms

I have a Dropdown Categories ..

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=faenas_combenef_category&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&order=asc&name=location') ?>
```

And my post Process... for tax

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {


$title      = trim($_POST['title']);
$content    = trim($_POST['description']);
$location   = trim($_POST['faenas_combenef_category']);


$my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $content,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'faenas',
            'tax_input'    => array( $location )
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
wp_set_object_terms($post_id,$location,'faenas_combenef_category');
    wp_redirect(home_url());
} // end IF

// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
```

And my taxonomy register .....

```
$labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Comunas de Beneficiarios', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Comuna de Beneficiario', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Buscar Comuna de Beneficiario' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'Comunas de Beneficiarios' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Editar Comuna de Beneficiario' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Actualizar Comuna de Beneficiario' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Añadir Nueva Comuna de Beneficiario' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nueva Comuna de Beneficiario' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Comuna Beneficiario' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'combenef' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'faenas_combenef_category', 'faenas', $args );
```

The post result OK but a "faenas_combenef_category" dont save in the custom post TAX please help, i dont know happend....

I change type of

My error was

```
$location   = trim($_POST['faenas_combenef_category']);
```

i rewrite this by

```
$location   = trim($_POST['location']);
```

But the post send value of Option and not the Name of Term of Taxonomy ....

My Post was

Title: Titledemo 
Description: 
Description Demo 
Location: 2

I need change this "2" by name of the Term of Taxonomy "faenas_combenef_category"

My print of dropdown categories is:

```
<select name="location" id="location" class="postform">
    <option class="level-0" value="2">Canela</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="5">Tambillos</option>
</select>
```

I need locate a solution please

SOLVED

I add function :

```
function custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy ) {
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    if ( $terms ) {
        printf( '<select name="%s" class="postform">', esc_attr( $taxonomy ) );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            printf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>', esc_attr( $term->slug ), esc_html( $term->name ) );
        }
        print( '</select>' );
    }
}
```

And change

```
$location   = trim($_POST['faenas_combenef_category']);
```

And print my new dropdown

```
<p><?php custom_taxonomy_dropdown( 'faenas_combenef_category' ); ?></p>
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Can you just do print_r($location); and tell me what is the output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used wrong tax_input parameter value for [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function it should be array like this

```
array( 'taxonomy_name' => array( 'term', 'term2', 'term3' ) )
```

as shown in the following code

```
$my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'faenas',
        'tax_input'    => array( 'faenas_combenef_category' => array( $location ) )
);
```

Comment: +1 from me, tax_input accept array of taxonomy terms, which asker was ignored.

Comment: respective changes made ​​and still the same problem

Comment: This is my print of my dropdown categories

<select name="location" id="location" class="postform">
    <option class="level-0" value="2">Canela</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="5">Tambillos</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

My error was

```
$location   = trim($_POST['faenas_combenef_category']);
```

i rewrite this by

```
$location   = trim($_POST['location']);
```

But the post send value of Option and not the Name of Term of Taxonomy ....

My Post was

Title:  Titledemo
Description: Description Demo
Location: 2

I need change this "2" by name of the Term of Taxonomy "faenas_combenef_category"